# plural form of "thematic"

Tags: irregular-plurals

Is the plural form of thematic "thematics"?

I did some researches and it is very rarely written with an s. Also, **word** considers it a mistake and underlines it. Yet, I found it in some online dictionaries (but they were not really reliable websites).

Comment: Yes, it is a plural noun. It's always used in the plural.

Comment: Word processors underline the strangest things (yes, intended both ways). In a dispute between a word processor and a dictionary about the spelling of a word, the dictionary usually prevails.

Comment: see _thematiques_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the source of your confusion lies in the fact that the word "**thematic" is listed as an adjective**, that cannot have a plural form.

According to "my trusted source" **LDOCE**, the word **thematics does not exist**.

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/thematic

Ditto for Cambridge: 
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thematic

While there are: **semantic** versus **semantics**. It seems there's just **no such option for thematic**.

Comment: _Semantics_ is a plural noun. _Thematic_ is not a noun, and thus does not have a plural.

Comment: Non-appearance in the OED even is stated by the editors **not** to be proof that a candidate is not in the lexis.

Comment: *Thematic* as a noun and *thematics* as "plural noun construed as singular" **are** in the OED and have been since 1912.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put anything past literary criticism.  It appears that "thematic" is now a noun, so I suppose there can be a plural "thematics."  From a book description on the Oxford University Press website:

"The first book-length study of the incest thematic in eighteenth-century Gothic literature"

"by offering a complex and multifaceted account of this neglected yet pervasive thematic"

(I apologize for the unsavory subject matter.)  I wonder what the exact distinction is between "theme" and "thematic."

Answer (score 0):

[ODO/Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/thematic) has now confirmed that the noun polyseme has achieved 'word' status:

> **thematic** noun
>
> 1 *thematics* treated as singular or plural: A body of topics for
>   study or discussion.
>
> ‘I soon gave up trying to prime him with the thematics of the piece’
>
> 2 *thematic* [British] [count usage; plural -s] A postage stamp forming part of a set with
>   designs connected with the same subject.
>
> ‘You can discuss ideas of what to collect - thematics will probably be
>   most suitable for beginners.’
>
> Also called topical

[tidied and clarified slightly]